# Adding a directory to the load path in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

As of Rails 2.3, what's the right way to add a directory to the load path so that it hooks into Rails' auto-reloading mechanisms?

The specific example I'm thinking of is I have a class that has several sub-classes using STI and I thought it would be a good idea to put them in a sub-directory rather than clutter the top-level.  So I would have something like:

```
#app/models/widget.rb
class Widget < ActiveRecord::Base
   add_to_load_path File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "widgets")
end

#app/models/widgets/bar_widget.rb
class BarWidget < Widget
end

#app/models/widgets/foo_widget.rb
class FooWidget < Widget
end
```

It's the `add_to_load_path` method that I'm looking for.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

In the current version of Rails (3.2.8), this has been changed in the application.rb file.

The code is currently commented out as:

```
  # Custom directories with classes and modules you want to be autoloadable.
  # config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/extras)
```

Will need to update the **autoload_paths** value.  Attempting to modify the the former **load_paths** variable causes this error.

```
/configuration.rb:85:in `method_missing': undefined method `load_paths' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0xac670b4> (NoMethodError)
```

for an example, for each path to add to autoload_paths config, add a line similar to the following:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/validators)
```

---

`config.autoload_paths` accepts an array of paths from which Rails will autoload constants. **Default is all directories under `app`.**

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html

---

From commentor (hakunin) below:

If the directory is under `app/`, you don't need to add it anywhere, it should just work by default (definitely in 3.2.12). Rails has `eager_load_paths` that acts as `autoload_paths` in development, and eager load in production. **All `app/*` directories are automatically added there.**

Comment: You are answering a 3 year old question, and rails 3 did not exists when this question was asked

Comment: Bro, you know the search engine Google, it lists 3 year old search results-all the time. Wouldn't it be nice if the 3 year old result could answer your question and end your quest sooner?

Comment: Of course, but this question has an accepted answer already, so the questioner already got an answer to his question.

Comment: @Bassetassen - StackOverflow is intended to be a repository of question and answers that are relevant and applicable at all times. When things change (ie. version updates), answers should be updated appropriately or new answers given. pocket-full-of-quarters did the right thing.

Comment: for the record I am very glad this response was posted. The accepted answer is no longer correct.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer this old question - you definitely saved me time. I hate how many people on this site think it should work the way they believe it should.

Comment: If the directory is under `app/`, you don't need to add it anywhere, it should just work by default (definitely in 3.2.12). Rails has `eager_load_paths` that acts as autoload_paths in development, and eager load in production. All `app/*` directories are automatically added there.

Comment: This is when I really wish I could down vote a comment.

Comment: For anyone wondering, @hakunin's comment still holds true for Rails 4. Any directory added in `app/*` will work.

Comment: This does not seem to work in Rails 6.  I added rb files to a path `app/controllers/viewmodels`, and ruby has no idea they exist.  I also have to restart the puma server every time I change one, unlike everything else which detects changes fine.

Answer (score 64):

For **older versions** of Rails:

You can do this in your environment.rb config file.

```
config.load_paths << "#{RAILS_ROOT}/app/widgets"
```

--

For **Rails 3**, see answers bellow

Comment: ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths << "#{RAILS_ROOT}/app/widgets"

Comment: See answer by pocket-full-of-quarters which is actually correct. This one is now out of date.

Answer (score 33):

In **Rails 5** you don't have to explicitly load folders from within the app directory anymore. All folders placed inside are directly available. You don't have to touch any of the config files. But it seems as if there are some issues with Spring.

The new workflow therefore is:

1. create a new folder and class inside the /app directory
2. run `spring stop` on the command line
3. check the autoload-paths with `bin/rails r 'puts ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths'` on the command line. The new folder should now be listed.
4. run `spring start` on the command line

Comment: I am finding this one unreliable & I never had spring installed or in my gemfile (when executed).  By unreliable I mean the puts code finds the directory but none of the files in it are loaded to include elsewhere. Including classes does work for me when I put the autoload_path in the config/application.rb instead.

Comment: @Mirv - which rails version are you on? and have a look at: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#autoload-paths

Comment: Yea, I read those & then tested on rails 5.0.0 & 5.1.0 in cloud9's IDE.  It apparently doesn't handle like normal changes to the files when running `rails s`, but instead I have to `reload!` while in `rails c`, which isn't mentioned for 3 more sections of the documentation!  I went back & checked, right now as it stands for my project - I have to manually add the file even though it's located in app/classes/filler.rb while using `rails c` ... I even restarted the workspace, though I haven't started a completely fresh project.

Comment: works for me, thanks. `spring server` is correct for 2019 instead of `spring start`

Comment: Oh spring... Thanks! You saved me.

Comment: thanks man, you saved my time.

Answer (score 27):

In Rails 3, you can set this in config/application.rb, where this sample is provided by default:

```
# Add additional load paths for your own custom dirs
# config.load_paths += %W( #{config.root}/extras )
```

Comment: # config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/extras)

Answer (score 13):

On Rails 5 you need to add the following code to environment.rb:

```
# Add the widgets folder to the autoload path
Rails.application.configure do
  config.autoload_paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/widgets"
end
```

Comment: Rails 5 actually autoloads all folders in the app directory.

Comment: Thanks. This was the default behaviour last time I checked, but honestly I can't remember if it was a production only issue like stated in here: http://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/08/29/rails-5-disables-autoloading-after-booting-the-app-in-production.html

Answer (score 8):

Another update for rails 3 -- activesupport 3.0.0:

Instead of:

```
ActiveSupport::Dependencies.load_paths << "#{RAILS_ROOT}/app/widgets"
```

You may need to do this:

```
ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths << "#{RAILS_ROOT}/app/widgets"
```

Comment: Rails.root is necessary in Rails 3 instead of RAILS_ROOT

Comment: Under Rails 3.0.3, I had to use 

ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths += %W( #{Rails.root.to_s}/app/libs )

Answer (score 1):

I found I needed to do this after config block-- no access to config object anymore.

This did the trick

```
ActiveSupport::Dependencies.load_paths << "#{RAILS_ROOT}/app/widgets"
```

Comment: doesn't work on Rails 6, see methods with `ActiveSupport::Dependencies.methods`

Answer (score 1):

In `config/application.rb` add `config.autoload_paths << "#{config.root}/models/widgets"`.

File should look like this:

```
module MyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.autoload_paths << "#{config.root}/models/widgets"
  end
end
```

I know this works for Rails 4 and 5. Probably others as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add multiple directories:

```rb
config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root / "components/*/app/public"]
```

(this is an example for packwerk autoload)

Comment: Thanks Dorian this is exactly what i needed to do (specifically for packwerk) and I spent over an hour trying to get it working! Thanks for sharing