# Is it possible to have a dynamic id column in Rails 3 when using single table inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, single-table-inheritance

I have a Change model that utilizes single table inheritance that has the following attributes:

```
id
type    #this is a single table inheritance type field.
description
dynamic_id
```

I also have two sub classes, Race which is a subclasses of Change and Workout which is a sub class of Race.

```
class Race < Change

end

class Workout < Race

end
```

I have a fourth class called Track and I'd like to create the following four associations by just using the dynamic_id field in the Change object. (i.e. I have not explicitly added race_id and workout_id to the Change table. Instead I want to use the dynamic_id as the race_id for the Race class and the dynamic_id as the workout_id for the Workout class)  By doing this, I will avoid having a lot of nil fields in my database.)

Here are the four associations I'm trying to create.

1. Race Model - belongs_to :track
2. Workout Model -  belongs_to :track
3. Track Model - has_many :races
4. Track Model - has_many :workouts

I've been trying to accomplish this with associations using :class_name and :foreign_key, but I can't seem to get it working.  Is this actually possible. I realize its probably not a best practice, but I'd still like to see if it doable. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for are "polymorphic associations". You can find more in the rails guides: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

Your case is a bit special because you want to use polymorphic associations with STI. I remember that there was a bug with this combination but it could be fixed by now.

I did not read it completely but this blog post seems to describe the situation: http://www.archonsystems.com/devblog/2011/12/20/rails-single-table-inheritance-with-polymorphic-association/

The problem I encountered with polymorphic associations and STI is described here: [Why polymorphic association doesn't work for STI if type column of the polymorphic association doesn't point to the base model of STI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9628610/why-polymorphic-association-doesnt-work-for-sti-if-type-column-of-the-polymorph)