# Combine STI and polymorphic with rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sti, polymorphism

I'm running with some issues trying to combine STI and polymorphic associations with the following structure :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Runner < User
  has_many :subscriptions, as: :subscriber, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :areas, through: :subscriptions
end

class Trainer < Runner
end

class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :subscriber, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :area
end

class Area
end
```

When I try in the console :

Runner.find(2101).areas

```
SELECT "areas".* FROM "areas" INNER JOIN "subscriptions" ON "areas"."id" = 
"subscriptions"."area_id" WHERE "subscriptions"."subscriber_id" = $1 AND 
"subscriptions"."subscriber_type" = $2  [["subscriber_id", 2101], ["subscriber_type", 
"User"]]
 => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
```

However there is a record with this runner :

```
 #<Subscription id: 3, area_id: 2, subscriber_id: 2101, subscriber_type: "Runner", primary_area: true>
```

But I don't understand why active record is looking for a User and not a Runner.

Any idea why ? or better design ?

Comment: Here is a very similar question with more answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9628610/why-polymorphic-association-doesnt-work-for-sti-if-type-column-of-the-polymorph

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From rails documentation

> Using polymorphic associations in combination with single table
>   inheritance (STI) is a little tricky. In order for the associations to
>   work as expected, ensure that you store the base model for the STI
>   models in the type column of the polymorphic association. To continue
>   with the asset example above, suppose there are guest posts and member
>   posts that use the posts table for STI. In this case, there must be a
>   type column in the posts table.

Change your subscription class like this

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :subscriber, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :area

  def subscriber_type=(sType)
     super(sType.to_s.classify.constantize.base_class.to_s)
  end
end
```