# rails 4: polymorphic set base class type instead of inherited

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sti, polymorphism

I have problem with rails relations. I have base model ant his inherited version

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Admin < User
end
```

Next I have membership model with polymorphic association

```
class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group
  belongs_to :membershipable, polymorphic: true
end
```

When I tryied to make new instance of Membership model, by typing for example

```
Membership.new group: Group.first, membershipable: Admin.first
```

membershipable_type is setting to "User" instead of "Admin". So i create before_validation callback

```
def proper_sti_type
  self.membershipable_type = memebrshipable.class.name
end
```

and it works, but i guess is better way to do this. Maybe someone know the better solution?

Thanks

Tom

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why polymorphic association doesn't work for STI if type column of the polymorphic association doesn't point to the base model of STI?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9628610/why-polymorphic-association-doesnt-work-for-sti-if-type-column-of-the-polymorph)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this inside your User model in-order to get the membershipable_type as 'Admin'

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships, as: :membershipable
end
```

This is because you are extending your admin model from user so it must have the association with membership model.
Then when you do this:

```
Membership.new group: Group.first, membershipable: Admin.first
```

you will get membershipable_type as "User".