# "has_many :through" association through a polymorphic association with STI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model, polymorphic-associations

I have two models that use the `people` table: `Person` and `Person::Employee` (which inherits from `Person`). The `people` table has a `type` column.

There is another model, `Group`, which has a polymorphic association called `:owner`. The `groups` table has both an `owner_id` column and an `owner_type` column.

---

*app/models/person.rb:*

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :group, as: :owner
end
```

*app/models/person/employee.rb:*

```
class Person::Employee < Person
end
```

*app/models/group.rb:*

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :owner, polymorphic: true
    belongs_to :supervisor
end
```

---

The problem is that when I create a Person::Employee with the following code, the `owner_type` column is set to an incorrect value:

```
group = Group.create
=> #<Group id: 1, owner_id: nil, owner_type: nil ... >
group.update owner: Person::Employee.create
=> true
group
=> #<Group id: 1, owner_id: 1, owner_type: "Person" ... >
```

`owner_type` should be set to `"Person::Employee"`, but instead it is set to `"Person"`.

---

Strangely, this doesn't seem to cause any problems when calling `Group#owner`, but it does cause issues when creating an association like the following:

*app/models/supervisor.rb:*

```
class Supervisor < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :groups
    has_many :employees, through: :groups, source: :owner, 
                         source_type: 'Person::Employee'
end
```

With this type of association, calling `Supervisor#employees` will yield no results because it is querying for `WHERE "groups"."owner_type" = 'People::Employees'` but `owner_type` is set to `'People'`.

Why is this field getting set incorrectly and what can be done about it?

---

**Edit:**

According to [this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord%3a%3aAssociations%3a%3aClassMethods-label-Polymorphic+Associations), the `owner_type` field is *not* getting set incorrectly, but it is working as designed and setting the field to the name of the *base* STI model.

The problem appears to be that the has_many :through association searches for `Group`s with a `owner_type` set to the model's *own* name, instead of the *base* model's name.

What is the best way to set up a `has_many :employees, through: :group` association that correctly queries for `Person::Employee` entries?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using Rails 4, so you can set a scope on your association. Your `Supervisor` class could look like:

```
class Supervisor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :groups
  has_many :employees, lambda {
    where(type: 'Person::Employee')
  }, through: :groups, source: :owner, source_type: 'Person'
end
```

Then you can ask for a supervisor's employees like `supervisor.employees`, which generates a query like:

```
SELECT "people".* FROM "people" INNER JOIN "groups" ON "people"."id" = 
"groups"."owner_id" WHERE "people"."type" = 'Person::Employee' AND
"groups"."supervisor_id" = ? AND "groups"."owner_type" = 'Person' 
[["supervisor_id", 1]]
```

This lets you use the standard association helpers (e.g., `build`) and is slightly more straightforward than your edit 2.

Answer (score 0):

I did came up with this workaround, which adds a callback to set the correct value for `owner_type`:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :owner, polymorphic: true
    before_validation :copy_owner_type

    private

    def copy_owner_type
        self.owner_type = owner.type if owner
    end
end
```

But, I don't know if this is the best and/or most elegant solution.

---

**Edit:**

After finding out that the `owner_type` field is *supposed* to be set to the base STI model, I came up with the following method to query for `Person::Employee` entries through the `Group` model:

```
class Supervisor < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :groups

    def employees
        Person::Employee.joins(:groups).where(
            'people.type' => 'Person::Employee',
            'groups.supervisor_id' => id
        )
    end
end
```

However, this does not seem to cache its results.

---

**Edit 2:**

I came up with an even more elegant solution involving setting the has_many :through association to associate with the base model and then creating a scope to query only the inherited model.

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
    scope :employees, -> { where type: 'Person::Employee' }
end

class Supervisor < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :groups
    has_many :people, through: :groups, source: :owner, source_type: 'Person'
end
```

With this I can call `Supervisor.take.people.employees`.

Comment: Have you tested it? Is having `Person` actually causes any issues?

Comment: I clarified my question, but the issue comes up when doing a has_many :through relationship that points to the `belongs_to :owner` relationship. I _have_ tested this code and so far it seems to work well.

Comment: OK, I'm asking because of this question, which is basicaly the reverse of what you do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9628610/why-polymorphic-association-doesnt-work-for-sti-if-type-column-of-the-polymorph

Comment: Ok, so that clarifies that `owner_type` is supposed to be the name of the _base_ model. That makes me feel like my workaround is a bit of a kludge. The question is, how would I search for only `Group`s that have an `owner` of the model `Person::Employee`?