# Overriding methods in an ActiveSupport::Concern module which are defined by a class method in the same module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activesupport, overriding, activesupport-concern

I have an ActiveSupport::Concern module which looks roughly like the following:

```
module MyModel
  module Acceptance

    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do
      enum status: [:declined, :accepted]
    end

    def declined!
      self.status = :declined
      # some extra logic
      self.save!
    end

    def accepted!
      self.status = :accepted
      # some extra logic
      self.save!
    end
  end
end
```

This is only ever going to be included into ActiveRecord classes, hence the use of `enum`. Basically, I'm overriding the `declined!` and `accepted!` methods that are created by `ActiveRecord::Enum.enum` with some extra, custom logic of my own.

The problem is, this doesn't work, because when I call `@model.declined!` it justs call the original implementation of `declined!` and ignores my custom method.

Looks like my custom methods are being included into the calling class **before** the included block is being run - meaning my custom methods are being overridden by the ones defined by `enum`, instead of the other way around.

There some easy workarounds in this particular situation (e.g. I could move the call `enum` back into the including class and make sure it's above the line `include MyModel::Acceptance`, but I'm wondering if there's a way I can solve this problem while keeping it all in the same module.

Is there any way I can call a class method within `included` that defines an instance method, then override that instance method from within the same `Concern` module?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you're looking for `define_method`.

```
module MyModel
  module Acceptance

    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do
      enum status: [:declined, :accepted]

      define_method :declined! do
        self.status = :declined
        # some extra logic
        self.save!
      end

      define_method :accepted! do
        self.status = :accepted
        # some extra logic
        self.save!
      end

    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on why this works? In Rails 3.2 @GeorgeMillo's way works well. In Rails 4.2 it doen't. Did they change something internally about how the methods are added?

Comment: I've just re-read the question and there's kind of an explanation there. But any extra info would be gratefully accepted :)