# Has many through, self related, and polymorphic for STI models saving STI parent class name instead of STI child class name

Tags: ruby-on-rails

guys we are building a sort of address book, we have Users, Contacts and a parent Table called UserEntity. We want to relate them in a many-to-many association through a table called Relationship, this relations have to be in a self related in UserEntity table.

One User has many Contacts and one Contact has many Users.

Later on we need relate new models with Users so the Relationship model must be polymorphic. We already built this:

```
class UserEntity < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "users"
end

class User < UserEntity
  has_many :relationships, as: :relatable
  has_many :contacts, through: :relationships, source: :relatable, source_type "Contact"
end

class Contact < UserEntity
  has_many :relationships, as: :relatable
  has_many :users, through: :relationships, source: :relatable, source_type "User"
end

class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :relatable, polymorphic: true
end
```

but when we try to save the association `user.contacts << contact` the `relatable_type` field saves "UserEntity" value and not "Contact" or "User" value. We already tried to do this without any favorable results http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#label-Polymorphic+Associations

How can we make that `relatable_type` value saves the model name ("Contact" || "User") and not the STI parent model name ("UserEntity")?

Comment: I'm sure there's a way, but I don't know if off the top of my head.  However, as an alternative, you could opt to not inherit from UserEntity for User and Contact; instead, use Concerns.  Breaking that inheritance chain will get you the right model names, while concerns will keep your code DRY.

Comment: Ok, that works! I know that is not the best solution, but it works jaja thanks a lot, I will keep trying with STI for a little more time.

Comment: This is a standard problem, changing the inheritance is one way to fix it but a hack. There is a solution to this -- using the `class` of the subclass, rather than the superclass. I have posted information (a solution is being worked on) which explains

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is something known as `STI` [`base class`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Inheritance/ClassMethods/base_class), whereby Rails will save the `Parent` class, even though you've called the `subclass`. We have experience with it:

[image]

The above should have `Node` as `Company`...

---

I spent some time last year looking over this; there's a `gem` called [`store_sti_base_class`](https://github.com/appfolio/store_base_sti_class):

> Notice that `addressable_type` column is `Person` even though the actual class is `Vendor`.
>
> Normally, this isn't a problem, however it can have negative performance characteristic in certain circumstances. The most obvious one is that a join with persons or an extra query is required to find out the actual type of addressable.

The way around it - at least from the perspective of the `gem` - is to extend `ActiveRecord` so that it will save the actual class of the model, not its parent.

The only code I have - which is out of date - is as follows:

```
#config/initializers/sti_base.rb
ActiveRecord::Base.store_base_sti_class = false

#lib/extensions/sti_base_class.rb
module Extensions
  module STIBaseClass #-> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2328984/rails-extending-activerecordbase
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do
      class_attribute :store_base_sti_class
      self.store_base_sti_class = true
    end
  end

  # include the extension 
  ActiveRecord::Base.send(:include, STIBaseClass)

  ####

  module AddPolymorphic
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do #-> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28214874/overriding-methods-in-an-activesupportconcern-module-which-are-defined-by-a-cl
      define_method :replace_keys do |record=nil|
        super(record)
        owner[reflection.foreign_type] = ActiveRecord::Base.store_base_sti_class ? record.class.base_class.name : record.class.name
        Rails.logger.info record.class.base_class.name
      end
    end
  end

  ActiveRecord::Associations::BelongsToPolymorphicAssociation.send(:include, AddPolymorphic)
end
```

As I need to get this working, it might be worth bantering something around.

Comment: Really? Did you use the gem or my code? Which version of Rails are you running?

Comment: We use the Gem, We have Rails 4.1.14 :) why you are suprised that worked? jaja with this we can do `user.contacts` but we are having trouble with `contact.users` but that relation in my case is no important.

Comment: Ah the `gem`, I was surprised because I thought you were using my code, which I was highly dubious would work out of the box

Answer (score 0):

You must set UserEntity as abstract class:

```
class UserEntity < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "users"
  self.abstract_class = true
end
```

Then value `relatable_type` can be `User` or `Contact`.

By default RoR save in `relatable_type` value of `base_class` method in your case:

```
class UserEntity < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class User < UserEntity
end

class Contact < UserEntity
end

irb(main):010:0> User.base_class.name 
=> "UserEntity"

irb(main):011:0> Contact.base_class.name 
=> "UserEntity"
```

When you make UserEntity as abstract class:

```
class UserEntity < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true 
end

class User < UserEntity
end

class Contact < UserEntity
end

irb(main):010:0> User.base_class.name 
=> "User"

irb(main):011:0> Contact.base_class.name 
=> "Contact"
```

Here defined method which store class name (https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/belongs_to_polymorphic_association.rb#L14):

```
def replace_keys(record)
  super
  owner[reflection.foreign_type] = record ? record.class.polymorphic_name : nil
end
```

```
def polymorphic_name
  base_class.name
end
```