# How to form a polymorphic has_many on an inherited class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, sti

In a Rails 4.2 app I have a model that inherits from [Draftsman](https://github.com/liveeditor/draftsman).

```
module ActsAs
  class Draft < Draftsman::Draft
    include ActsAs::Votable
  end
end
```

Users can vote to approve/reject edits, and the ActsAs::Votable mixin adds this polymorphic association and methods.

```
module ActsAs
  module Votable
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern
    included do
      has_many :votes_for, 
        class_name: 'ActsAs::Vote',
        as: :votable, 
        dependent: :destroy
    end
  end
end
```

This works fine for most parent models, but I am having trouble with this inherited Draftsman class.

I can create a vote

```
ActsAs::Vote.last
=> #<ActsAs::Vote id: 10, votable_id: 6, votable_type: "Draftsman::Draft">
```

but I am unable to return a draft's votes

```
@draft = ActsAs::Draft.find(6)
@draft.votes_for
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
```

I have tried modifying the vote creation method to set votable_type as ActsAs::Draft rather than the inherited Draftsman::Draft, but the same problem persists.

```
ActsAs::Vote.last
=> #<ActsAs::Vote id: 10, votable_id: 6, votable_type: "ActsAs::Draft">
@draft = ActsAs::Draft.find(6)
@draft.votes_for
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
```

The relationship is obviously not defined on Draftsmans::Draft

```
@draft = Draftsman::Draft.find(6)
@draft.votes_for
NoMethodError: undefined method `votes_for' for #<Draftsman::Draft:0x007fd7e6de9660>
```

Why am I unable to fetch the child votes via `@draft`, when `ActsAs::Vote.all` shows that the records exist in the table?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue when using polymorphic associations with STI.

See: [Why polymorphic association doesn't work for STI if type column of the polymorphic association doesn't point to the base model of STI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9628610/why-polymorphic-association-doesnt-work-for-sti-if-type-column-of-the-polymorph)

Personally, I'm dealing with this issue myself by using the `store_base_sti_class` (gem: https://github.com/appfolio/store_base_sti_class), which patches the STI behavior with Rails.

Comment: Thanks @anthony, I had come across this already, but this comment made be believe I should be able to call the child votes: `Rails transparently uses the STI base classname Staff as the target type and due to the fact that id's are always unique in an STI table it makes no difference whether the type is set to Guard or to Staff in the poly table the correct record will be fetched.` But perhaps I misunderstood this comment. Anyway, if I set `votable_type: "ActsAs::Draft"` I would expect to be able to call `ActAs::Draft.find(:id).votes_for`, correct? But I'm still getting an empty collection.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts on this. I think I may be missing something, so appreciate any help or ideas you have.

Comment: never mind. I must have had a bug elsewhere as this is now working as expected, and I can indeed call `ActAs::Draft.find(:id).votes_for`. Thanks for your help.