# Polymorphic Has_many Association with Polymorphic Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relationship

I have a problem with my polymorphic association.

role.rb

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :resource, polymorphic: true
end
```

structure.rb

```
class Structure < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :roles, as: :resource
end
```

association.rb

```
class Association < Structure
end
```

I have another model called User where I create role like Rolify does.

```
def add_role role_name, resource = nil
  role = Role.find_or_create_by(name: role_name.to_s,
    resource_type: (resource.is_a?(Class) ? resource.to_s : resource.class.name if resource),
    resource_id: (resource.id if resource && !resource.is_a?(Class)))

  if !roles.include?(role)
    self.roles << role
    self.save
  end
  role
end
```

So when I create a role for a user with an Association, I have :

`#<Role id: 2, name: "president", resource_id: 1, resource_type: "Association", created_at: "2018-02-28 23:04:20", updated_at: "2018-02-28 23:04:20">]`

But when I try to get all roles from Association, this is the SQL :

```
SELECT `roles`.* FROM `roles`  WHERE `roles`.`resource_id` = 1 AND `roles`.`resource_type` = 'Structure'
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking for. Please, rephrase it and make clear what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Why polymorphic association doesn't work for STI if type column of the polymorphic association doesn't point to the base model of STI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9628610/why-polymorphic-association-doesnt-work-for-sti-if-type-column-of-the-polymorph) - it looks like Rails does not support this out of the box (at least through Rails 4.2 - not sure which version you're using). It looks like the best solution may be to override the `_type` method. Also looks like there might be a gem: https://github.com/appfolio/store_base_sti_class

Comment: Thanks for your response, I user "scope" or custom function to do it...