# Association issues with `Polymorphic association does not support to compute class.` in polymorphic belongs_to with sti

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, polymorphism, associations, belongs-to

I meet a relationship creation problem when I try to create a new instance of an object, I get the error `Polymorphic association does not support to compute class.`.
I get this error uniquely on front-end, everything seems to work fine in console.

Here are classes:

*vizualization > base.rb*

```
module Vizualization
  class Base < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :vizualization_item, polymorphic: true
  end
end
```

*vizualization > foo_viz.rb*

```
module Vizualization
  class FooViz < Base
  end
end
```

*Foo.rb*

```
class Foo < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :vizualization, class_name: "Vizualization::FooViz",
                          as: :vizualization_item,
                          inverse_of: :vizualization_item
end
```

Relationship seems to work as I can do following requests:

- ParticipativeDatavizualization::FooViz.last.datavizualization_item
- FooViz.last.cfp.participative_datavizualization

Any idea why it could work on console but not in front-end ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Ps: I've already read these two posts, [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9628610/why-polymorphic-association-doesnt-work-for-sti-if-type-column-of-the-polymorph), 2, but I didn't reach any solution. Also tried [this gem](http://%20https://github.com/appfolio/store_base_sti_class) but i didn't get it working.

Comment: That does not sound like a vanilla rails error. I would suspect that there is something more a play here.

Answer (score 0):

I did the same associations as you, and it works well in both console and view.
I share my settings, maybe you can reference.

```rb
# 20200328045328_create_vizualization_bases.rb
class CreateVizualizationBases < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :vizualization_bases do |t|
      t.integer :vizualization_item_id
      t.string :vizualization_item_type
      t.string :type, index: true

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :vizualization_bases,  [:vizualization_item_type, :vizualization_item_id], name: 'inde_on_bases_for_poly'
  end
end

# 20200328045650_create_foos.rb
class CreateFoos < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :foos do |t|
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

# app/models/vizualization.rb
module Vizualization
  def self.table_name_prefix
    'vizualization_'
  end
end

# app/models/vizualization/base.rb
class Vizualization ::Base < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :vizualization_item, polymorphic: true
end

# app/models/vizualization/foo_viz.rb
class Vizualization::FooViz < Vizualization::Base
end

# config/routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root "application#hello"
end

# app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def hello
    @foo = Foo.first
    @foo_viz = @foo.vizualization
  end
end

# app/views/application/hello.html.erb
<h2>I'm Foo and my <%= "Id: #{@foo.id}, Class: #{@foo.class}" %></h2>
<h2>I'm FooViz and my <%= "Id: #{@foo_viz.id}, Class: #{@foo_viz.class}" %></h2>
```

then run in console:

```rb
foo = Foo.create
Vizualization::FooViz.create(vizualization_item: foo)
```

then go to http://localhost:3000, you can find

```html
I'm Foo and my Id: 1, Class: Foo
I'm FooViz and my Id: 1, Class: Vizualization::FooViz
```