# Run Rake Task without using Rake

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, helper

I have an app where users can bet each other and when the result are loaded into the app I use a Rake task to settle the bets. I'm running on Heroku so I'm using their Schedule service for this Rake task every half hour.

This works fine, but I would much more like to run the Rake job when the results are saved/updated in the database.

How do I convert the Rake task so I can run it from my model, which could look like the below. It could also be nice if I could run it from the controllers, since I might have several situations where a settlement process is needed.

```
class Spotprice < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :spotarea
  belongs_to :product

  after_save   :settlement
end
```

My Rake task looks like this right now:

```
task :settlement => :environment do
  puts "Settlement in progress..."
  puts "-------------------------"
  puts " "
  puts " "
  puts "BETS:"
  puts "-------------------------"

  # Bet settlement
  @bets = Bet.where(:settled => false)

  @bets.find_each do |bet|

    if not bet.choice.spotprice.nil?

      case 
      when bet.choice.spotprice.value > bet.choice.value && bet.buy == true
        profitloss  = 10
        puts "#{bet.id}: Win (1)"
      when bet.choice.spotprice.value < bet.choice.value && bet.buy == false 
        profitloss  = 10
        puts "#{bet.id}: Win (2)"
      when bet.choice.spotprice.value > bet.choice.value && bet.buy == false
        profitloss  = -10
        puts "#{bet.id}: Loose (3)"
      when bet.choice.spotprice.value < bet.choice.value && bet.buy == true 
        profitloss  = -10
        puts "#{bet.id}: Loose (4)"
      when bet.choice.spotprice.value == bet.choice.value
        profitloss  = -10
        puts "#{bet.id}: Loose (5)"
      end

      if profitloss  
        bet.settled    = true
        bet.profitloss = profitloss 
        bet.save
      end 

    end

    if bet.choice.settled == true
      bet.choice.settled = false
      bet.choice.save
    end

  end

  # Pusher update
  Pusher["actives"].trigger("updated", {:message => "Settlement completed"}.to_json)

end
```

Comment: You can just put it in a file in `lib` and then call it when you need to. You could do tricky things like setting up observers to watch when models are saved, and react accordingly. You could also use PrivatePub to send asynchronous methods to your view to do things like alerting the users.

Comment: Hi.. I just got the impression that it's not best practice to run Rake Tasks from models, controllers an so on.. That they should only be called from some kind of Cron. Have I got the wrong impression :)

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't explain myself very well. That was my fault. What I meant was you could take the code out of the rake task, and put it within a class in `lib`. You would no longer have a rake task. The code would just a regular ruby method (just houses in `lib` since it's not a model or anything) and then just call it from wherever.

Comment: See that makes more sense now :) Could you please show me how the file in the `lib`directory should look like.. Here I'm thinking of the start of the file - is is something with `Module`or should it be ´class Spotprice < ActiveRecord::Base´.. This is unknown grounds for me :) can I then just call the method with àfter_save :settlementprocess`in my model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just putting my comments from the original question in to an answer.

I had a similar situation where I had a rake task that I wanted to call from outside of rake. What you want to do is move the code from the rake task in to a ruby class, the best place for this would be in `lib`. Your class would look something like this:

```
# lib/settlement.rb
class Settlement
  def self.settle_bets
    # all the code that used to be in the rake task
  end
end
```

Then in code you can do something like this (random example):

```
# app/controllers/bets_controller.rb
#...
  def settle_bets
    require "settlement"
    Settlement.settle_bets
  end
# ...
```

Or (another random example):

```
# app/models/bet.rb
class Bet ...
  after_update: update_some_bets

  # ... more code here

  private
    def update_some_bets
      require "settlement"
      Settlement.settle_bets
    end
```

And you could still use the rake task if you wanted:

```
# lib/tasks/settlement.task
require "settlement"
# require "#{Rails.root}/lib/settlement.rb" # use this if the above won't work

task :settlement => :environment do
  Settlement.settle_bets
end
```

Comment: Now that looks like the way to go.. I'll give it a go and see if I can make it work and get back to you :) Thanks!

Comment: Perfect.. works just like I wanted it to.. thank you so much :) Have a nice day!

Comment: I suggest adding extra files into `autoload_path`. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223481/adding-a-directory-to-the-load-path-in-rails)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the results calculated when you update (or save), why not move most of the code from your rake task into a method of your Bet model, then call it which you call with an `after_update` callback

in `bet.rb`

```
# class method that settles the given bet
def self.settle(bet)
  message = nil
  if not bet.choice.spotprice.nil?
    case 
    when bet.choice.spotprice.value > bet.choice.value && bet.buy == true
      profitloss  = 10
      message =  "#{bet.id}: Win (1)"
    when bet.choice.spotprice.value < bet.choice.value && bet.buy == false 
      profitloss  = 10
      message =  "#{bet.id}: Win (2)"
    when bet.choice.spotprice.value > bet.choice.value && bet.buy == false
      profitloss  = -10
      message =  "#{bet.id}: Lose (3)"
    when bet.choice.spotprice.value < bet.choice.value && bet.buy == true 
      profitloss  = -10
      message =  "#{bet.id}: Lose (4)"
    when bet.choice.spotprice.value == bet.choice.value
      profitloss  = -10
      message =  "#{bet.id}: Lose (5)"
    end

    if profitloss  
      bet.settled    = true
      bet.profitloss = profitloss 
      bet.save
    end 
  end

  if bet.choice.settled == true
    bet.choice.settled = false
    bet.choice.save
  end
  # return message
  message
end
```

in `spot_price.rb`

```
class SpotPrice
  after_update Bet.settle(self)
  after_save   Bet.settle(self)

  ....
end
```

This doesn't handle the Pusher stuff our other output (which is saved and returned in the `message` variable).  Also, couldn't help myself, but I assumed you mean "Lose", not "Loose".

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Makes good sense, but I have more then one Class that needs to be settled on one run and I'm also running a task thats ranks the users based on their winnings. I would like to keep the code collected in one place.. Thanks for the typo by the way :)