# How to append a path to ruby's LOAD_PATH in the context of rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am writing a class outside my rails project. But I failed to make my AR model class file find it.

```
$: << "~/svn/ruby/rails/framework-rails-jxcommon/app/models"
require JXAttributeMethods

class Topic001 < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ::JXAttributeMethods

  attr_enum :tag ["aaa", "bb", "xxx"]

end
```

what is the best practice to append a path to ruby's LOAD_PATH in the context of rails?

Thanks.

Comment: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223481/adding-a-directory-to-the-load-path-in-rails)

Answer (score 2):

Paths must be expanded before they're valid. `~` is shell short-hand for "home directory" but it means nothing to the loader.

Try this:

```
$: << File.expand_path("~/svn/ruby/rails/framework-rails-jxcommon/app/models")
```

It's probably a bad idea to bake this sort of thing into your program, it locks it to your local organization method.

An alternative is to make it relative:

```
$: << File.expand_path("../framework-rails-jxcommon/app/models")
```

Don't forget that `require` takes a string argument, not a class.