# NameError (uninitialized constant Wizard)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I thought everything in the App folder autoloads. Why would I be getting an (uninitialized constant) error?

## app/form_models/user.rb

```
module Wizard
  module User
   end
end
```

I have been following these instructions.
https://medium.com/@nicolasblanco/developing-a-wizard-or-multi-steps-forms-in-rails-d2f3b7c692ce

However, keep getting error and the blog states:
" Remember that the Rails autoloading feature will load every Ruby class inside the app folder"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Rails auto-loader conventions this should be located in some path ending in `wizard/user.rb` but it's not.

One place to put it is `app/models/concerns/wizard/user.rb` where it can be loaded.

Comment: What are my other options, If I want to keep it in the form_model folder?

Comment: You either need to change the path or the name. They work in conjunction as far as the auto-loader is concerned. You could try and call it `app/form_models/wizard/user.rb` but you'd have to add `app/form_models` to your [autoload path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223481/adding-a-directory-to-the-load-path-in-rails). A viable option if that's what you prefer.